# How can I send parameters to AES encryptor?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, cbc-mode

I have to encrypt some parameters for a web portal that recibe encrypted parameters via POST with AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding, the encryption method was provided by the web portal creator(another team), but when I use their method the result is not accepted by ther web portal. I assume that the parameters are not well provided to the method. Am I missing somethig?

I requested some fixed IV value but the another teams told me that they used random IV's.

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plaintext, SecretKey key, byte[] IV) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);                
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);               
    return cipherText;
}
```

//this is the way I build the parameters

```
        String input_text = txtPlainText.getText();
        byte[] plaintext = input_text.getBytes("UTF-8");

        String encodedKey = "6qp4Y?kLmaY8+Fsd";
        byte[] decodedKey =  encodedKey.getBytes();
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");

        byte[] IV = new byte[16];
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        random.nextBytes(IV);

        byte[] cipherText = Encrypt(plaintext,key,IV);
        String Encrypted_text = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);

        txtEncryptedText.setText(Encrypted_text );
```

Every timeI use this encription method i get a diferent value, for the plain text 'System Administrator' I get  vlaues like 'U+za3baTIvMpiFgCPCfqoKe+ljDutraUrUTJhroqHPg=', 'lHT0Kq6GlyzYx2TEyQmqdPp4KfVi5sdlC0udtSlZ5uk='

Comment: if your initial vector is different then you will be getting different results only.

Comment: Are you OK with showing the public the value for variable `String encodedKey`?  The key looks to be sensitive information.

Comment: You need to get the IV and key from them

Comment: I know, but they insists that I can use the SecureRandom class to generate the IV, I wasn't used AES encryption before so I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Are you sender or the receiver? If sender, you have to send the IV, and the key must be agreed before.

Comment: I am the sender, They use the same key to decrypt, but for the IV they use the next code: SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(); random.nextBytes(IV);

Comment: No, they should use your IV to decrypt.

Comment: Normally the IV is *prepended* to the cipher and then the combined IV+cipher is base64 encoded prior to transmission.